# Can business name on account be obtained using the PayPal Rest API (missing in "get user information")?

Tags: api, rest, paypal

I am using the PayPal REST API "Login with PayPal" functionality to enable users to rapidly create an account on our site by PayPal OpenAuth login.  I want to ensure accounts are created with accurate information so PayPal API is used as a method of rapid validation.

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/log-in-with-paypal/detailed/

Using obtain authorization, and "get user information" this works perfectly and seemlessly with personal or premier accounts however for business accounts the business name is not returned.

```
GET https://api.paypal.com/v1/identity/openidconnect/userinfo/?schema=openid
```

Sample response

```
{
    "address":
    {
        "postal_code":"12345"
        "locality":"A CITY"
        "region":"XX"
        "country":"US"
        "street_address":"123 MAIN STREET"
    }
    "verified_account":"true"
    "name":"Joe Smith"
    "email":"Joe.Smith@paypal.com"
    "account_type":"PREMIER"
}
```

However for account_type=Business the user information doesn't return the business name. Strangely this is available in "classic" API "verification status" however it is a cludgy workaround to use REST API to request authorization, get a token, login, populate all info except the business name then use that to call the classic API just to obtain the business name.

Am I missing something or is this an oversight by PayPal.
Is there a reason the REST API provides personal but not business names?
Is there a reason the REST API doesn't provide business names but the "classic API" does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the REST API's do not return the business name of a Business account. There is a bunch of features being implemented in REST before the end of this year. I'm not sure if including the business name is one of them but I'll submit a Feature Request asking for the response to start including that information.

Comment: Thank you that would be helpful.  Being able to make a "clean break" from the "classic" API greatly increases the value of using the restful API.  Having to use both is possible but ugly.